# React Native (Expo) - useWindowDimensions().width not updated on orientation change

Tags: react-native, expo, responsive, device-orientation

I'm stuck with element sizes based on screen sizes when device orientation changes.
Here's my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

const CleanSearchBar = (props) => {
   const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;

   return (
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{left: (windowWidth - 127)}}>
         <Text>text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>);
}
```

It always keeps the initial value.
Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: Which RN version are you using? There is a bug from version 0.63.0 to 0.63.3 that will be fixed in the next version: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29323

Comment: Latest one for both RN and Expo

Comment: Ok so that's most likely the cause of your issue then. You could either use an older Expo version with RN 0.62.X, wait for RN 0.63.4 to release or use another library like https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks for instance, at least until the issue is fixed on RN/Expo

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think I'll stick freezing the app in portrait state. I also read about others still having issues, then I suppose it's indeed a RB bug: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/291